# HATEOAS standards / architectural pattern

Tags: json, api, rest, hateoas

if i am correct HATEOAS ist an architectural pattern and don't describe HOW a client should discover relations. HATEOAS just describe THAT a server should send a discoverable API to the client.

When adopting HATEOAS the api author can define HOW the client has to discover the relations.

For example without a standard like hydra / hal / jsonapi it's not clear if a json use "link", "_link", "links", "relations" fields in the json document to represent a relation.

From my point of view, this would allow me, as an api author to define something like this (valid HATEOAS):

The symbol "" represents an array of hypermedia controls

Hypermedia controls are represented by a string.

The string can start with the reserved symbols "✔", "↯" and "±".

If the hypermedia string starts with "✔", the client is allowed to do a safe GET request to the URL. the URL follows the "✔" symbol and is rot13 decoded.

```
{
    …
    "": [
       “✔uggc://.../traerf/snagnfl”
    ]
}
```

From my point of view, this should be valid HATEOAS, or did i miss something?

Of course defining an own standard ontop of HATEOAS doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such standard or architectural pattern like "HATEOAS". There is REST(Representational State Transfer) Architectural **Style**(Style not pattern or something else) that comprises several constraints. One of the **constraints** is called as a - "Hypermedia as the Engine of Application State".

> If the hypermedia string starts with "✔", the client is allowed to do
>   a safe GET request to the URL. the URL follows the "✔" symbol and is
>   rot13 decoded.

All of these are irrelevant(and pure design), only thing that matters is selected hypermedia type(HTML, Atom, Collection+JSON etc) and hypertext controls like:

- <a href="..."
- <img src="..."
- <link href="..."
- <form method="..." action="..."

that are defined by media type and not by conventions like "if the URL follows the symbol" etc...